# Google Colab: Can I cache the Google Drive authentication?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-colaboratory

Can I cache the Google Drive authentication?

I tried reusing the previous OAUTH token, but that didn't work.

Comment: Yes. Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo What context? Currently I have to re-auth every ~6 hours or so; I want a solution where a single auth works for, say, a month.

Comment: Can you provide your code?